# Pfsense source code to build firewall

Tags: kernel, openbsd, pfsense

Pfsense is an open source Firewall based on openBSD kernel.

Where can I find the code and how to modify it to build my firewall?

Comment: one minute of googling gets you to the source [here](https://doc.pfsense.org/index.php?title=Comparison_to_Commercial_Alternatives&action=edit) use your own login info to view it. Are you sure you want to build this on your firewall and not just run a (cross) compiled version on it? Update your question with information about the hardware that you have, what modifications to the standard Pfsense installers you need and other relevant information.

Comment: I want to learn how to make a firewall.
I lack the skills to make such a firewall because I do not know how to program with the Kernel. I have an intermediate knowledge of C/C++ and extensive knowledge of VB and C#.

Does anyone know of someone who could help me learn how to program Kernel drivers and the like. and if not, does anyone know where I could get some information so I can start learning it myself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As indicated on the website the actual code is available via GitHub for you to look at.

https://www.pfsense.org/get-involved/

https://github.com/pfsense/

The other choice is to examine the relevant web server configuration file to find the location the web front-end files so that you can track down other relevant files to modify for your project (I've done similar things with other software appliance type devices before but you need to understand that it's a slippery slope. If it's not designed well then you can end up in a mess and you might even have been better of starting from scratch though I doubt that it's the case here...).

Obviously, you can modify it in a million different ways once you have access to the actual files including direct modification and via a WYSIWYG editor.

You subsequent comment/s seem to be jumping from one place to another...

This is something that you can't learn simply be reading by thinking about it from the start and then picturing how the whole thing will work without adequate background knowledge.

Even if you have adequate background knowledge there are a lot of practical issues that you need to deal with (you'll figure this out) such as how everything fits together. It's not a single thing you're asking. You're asking for how to seemingly solve many sub-problems as well.

Like I said the best way to do this is to learn by doing. Namely, working on the problem and researching at the same time.

Moreover, based on what I'm seeing you don't really know what you're getting yourself into. I've done this. One minute you'll be stuck working on a piece of HTML, the next you could be working on a CGI script in BASH, Perl, or Python, and the next working on something at the operating system level in C/C++.

Saying that you know one language or another is not going to help you in this context. Flexibility, resilience, and desire are the keys if you want to complete your project successfully.

If you want to do this the best way to get involved may be simply to get involved with existing projects (such as pfSense) and then fork it to suit your needs, ask members involved in these projects to help you, etc...

Else start from scratch by yourself and then attempt to break the problem down and ask questions here and on other online forums until problem completion.

For kernel level modifications there are already many different resources out there. As stated before though, based on the way you've phrased things you could simply be building a custom web interface for a firewall appliance based on a BSD core or else a firewall/operating system from scratch. You need to figure out how far you want to take it and then just work on it.

Based on what I know of other people, if you sit on it and just read you'll figure out the scale of what you're contemplating and then pull back or out of the project entirely. Just start working on it...

http://www.freesoftwaremagazine.com/articles/writing_a_kernel_module_for_freebsd

https://www.freebsd.org/doc/en_US.ISO8859-1/books/

http://www.nostarch.com/bsddrivers.htm

This is a Linux resource but core theories are the same. It may be useful to you.

http://www.oreilly.com/openbook/linuxdrive3/book/